# getting error as `This version of CLI is only compatible with Angular versions ^16.0.0, but Angular version15.2.9 was found instead.` angular 14 - 15

Tags: migration, angular15

After migrating from angular14 to 15 getting error
dependencies and dev-dependencis
"dependencies": {
"@angular/animations": "15.2.9",
"@angular/cdk": "15.2.9",
"@angular/common": "15.2.9",
"@angular/compiler": "15.2.9",
"@angular/core": "15.2.9",
"@angular/forms": "15.2.9",
"@angular/material": "15.2.9",
"@angular/material-moment-adapter": "15.2.9",
"@angular/platform-browser": "15.2.9",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "15.2.9",
"@angular/router": "15.2.9",
"@angular/service-worker": "15.2.9",
"@batavia/app-footer": "10.0.0-rc.0",
"@batavia/app-header": "10.0.0-rc.0",
"@batavia/app-menu": "10.0.0-rc.0",
"@batavia/core": "10.0.0-rc.0",
"@batavia/schematics": "^1.0.4",
"@batavia/shared": "10.0.0-rc.0",
"@halodoc/erx": "4.0.0",
"@halodoc/eslint-config": "2.0.0",
"@halodoc/module-federation": "15.0.0-beta.2",
"@ngx-translate/core": "14.0.0",
"@tweenjs/tween.js": "18.5.0",
"@types/googlemaps": "3.39.2",
"bootstrap": "4.4.1",
"core-js": "3.6.4",
"deepmerge-ts": "^4.2.2",
"font-awesome": "4.7.0",
"jquery": "^3.6.0",
"luxon": "1.28.1",
"moment": "2.29.4",
"moment-timezone": "0.5.27",
"ngx-build-plus": "^15.0.0",
"ngx-drag-scroll": "8.0.0-beta.2",
"ngx-material-timepicker": "^5.5.3",
"ngx-order-pipe": "2.0.4",
"ngx-translate-multi-http-loader": "9.3.1",
"read-excel-file": "^5.2.25",
"rrule": "2.7.1",
"rxjs": "6.5.4",
"rxjs-multi-scan": "1.0.2",
"ts-md5": "^1.2.10",
"tslib": "^2.0.0",
"underscore": "1.12.1",
"uuid": "3.4.0",
"zone.js": "~0.11.4"
},
"devDependencies": {
"@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^15.2.9",
"@angular-devkit/build-optimizer": "0.803.5",
"@angular/cli": "^15.2.9",
"@angular/compiler-cli": "^15.2.9",
"@angular/language-service": "15.2.9",
"@halodoc/tailwind-config": "1.0.0",
"@types/datatables.net": "^1.10.21",
"@types/jasmine": "~3.6.0",
"@types/jasminewd2": "^2.0.10",
"@types/jquery": "^3.5.9",
"@types/node": "^12.20.37",
"@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.23.0",
"@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.23.0",
"autoprefixer": "^10.4.14",
"codelyzer": "^6.0.0",
"eslint": "^8.15.0",
"eslint-plugin-unused-imports": "^2.0.0",
"husky": "^8.0.1",
"jasmine-core": "~3.6.0",
"jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
"karma": "6.4.0",
"karma-chrome-launcher": "3.1.1",
"karma-cli": "~2.0.0",
"karma-coverage": "^2.2.0",
"karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
"karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.0",
"karma-parallel": "^0.3.1",
"karma-spec-reporter": "0.0.32",
"lint-staged": "^12.4.1",
"nyc": "^15.1.0",
"postcss": "^8.4.21",
"pre-commit": "^1.2.2",
"prettier": "^2.0.5",
"pretty-quick": "^2.0.2",
"tailwindcss": "^3.3.1",
"ts-node": "~8.6.2",
"typescript": "4.9.5",
"unimported": "^1.21.0",
"webpack-bundle-analyzer": "^3.9.0"
},

try deleting node modules and again reinstall node modules also tried to build with @angular-builders/custom-webpack15.0.0
my local environmemt[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VfpYt.png)